# How to implement compareTo()?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, compareto

what is wrong in this Code. The Compiler said, that the method `compareTo(T)` is undefined for the type `T`.

```
public ArrayList<T> sortieren(ArrayList<T> list, int type)
    {
        
        if (list.size() > 1)
        {
            for (int y = list.size(); y > 0; y--)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < y-1; x++)
                {
                    
                    if (list.get(x).compareTo(list.get(x+1)) > 0)
                    {
                        anzahlVergleiche++;
                        
                        // tausch von zwei Elementen
                        T temp = list.get(x);
                        list.set(x,list.get(x+1));
                        list.set(x+1,temp);
                        
                        anzahlVertauschungen++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        anzahlVergleiche++;
                    }
                        
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: How is `T` declared?

Comment: T is the type of my ArrayList

Comment: Yes. But how is it declared? You're getting that error because `T` is not comparable. And that boils down to how you declared it.

Comment: I dont declare it. I create some Arrays like ArrayList<Integer> and ArrayList<Double>. And these Lists call the method "sortieren".

Comment: If you didn't declare `T` then the code would not compile on the method declaration too. Is this method in a generic class (where something like `<T...>` comes after the class name)?

Comment: yes. "public class Bubblesort<T>

Comment: Yes, that's where your problem is. `T` must be made comparable, so you need to declare your class as `public class Bubblesort<T extends Comparable<T>>`, which will in turn make sure that the values you add to your array list are of comparable types only.

Comment: There is one more Problem. In my Factory i return "new Bubblesort()" . This is an error. But return "new Bubblesort<T extends Comparable <T>>()" or return "new Bubblesort<T> does not work too

Comment: okay i made it!

Comment: If your question was answered, you could either answer it yourself if you feel it would help others or maybe close it as a duplicate of some other question you found that was the same.